# minecraft clickgui is broken

Tags: java, minecraft

so i was following the tutorial but it bugs
the tutorial: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clonDGFq49Y\](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clonDGFq49Y%5C)
The bug:
[image]

The bug is when i want to have long name in the hack it disappears
Please help
i will shot the code:\

```java
package sonikhack.render;

import java.io.IOException;

import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiButton;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen;
import sonikhack.Client;
import sonikhack.module.Module;
import sonikhack.module.Category;

public class ClickGui extends GuiScreen{

    
    @Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        drawDefaultBackground();
        drawRect(150, 2, 220, 14, 0xffff6052);
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString("Combat", 152, 4, 0xffffffff);
        drawRect(250, 2, 322, 14, 0xffff6052);
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString("Movement", 252, 4, 0xffffffff);
        drawRect(350, 2, 432, 14, 0xffff6052);
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString("Render", 352, 4, 0xffffffff);
        drawRect(450, 2, 506, 14, 0xffff6052);
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString("Misc", 452, 4, 0xffffffff);
        super.drawScreen(mouseX, mouseY, partialTicks);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean doesGuiPauseGame() {
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public int placeForHackY(Module m) {
        
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.COMBAT)) return Category.placeInListCombat(m) * 14;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.MOVEMENT)) return Category.placeInListMovement(m) * 14;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.RENDER)) return Category.placeInListRender(m) * 14;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.MISC)) return Category.placeInListMisc(m) * 14;
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    public int placeForHackX(Module m) {
        
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.COMBAT)) return 150;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.MOVEMENT)) return 250;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.RENDER)) return 350;
        if(m.getCategory().equals(Category.MISC)) return 450;
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    public void initGui() {
            for(int i = 1; i < Client.modules.size(); i++) {
                Module m = Client.modules.get(i);
                buttonList.add(new GuiButton(i, placeForHackX(m), placeForHackY(m), 25 + (m.getName().length() * 3) + m.getName().length(), 14, m.getName()));
            }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void actionPerformed(GuiButton button) throws IOException {
        for(int i= 1; i < Client.modules.size(); i++) {
            if(button.id == i) {
                Client.getModules().get(i).toggle();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the clickgui
now category:

```java
package sonikhack.module;

import sonikhack.Client;

    public enum Category {
        COMBAT("Combat"),
        MOVEMENT("Movement"),
        RENDER("Render"),
        MISC("Misc");
    
        public String name;
        public int moduleIndex;
    
        Category(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


    public static int size(Category cat) {
        
        int i = 0;
        
        
        for(Module m : Client.getModules()) {
            if(m.getCategory().equals(cat)) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        return 0;
    }

    public static int placeInListRender(Module m) {
        
        
        int i = 0;
        
        for(Module mod : Client.getModules()) {
            if(mod.getCategory().equals(RENDER) && !mod.equals(m)) {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            
            if(mod.getCategory().equals(RENDER) && mod.equals(m)) {
                return i;
            }
            
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
    public static int placeInListMovement(Module m) {
        
        
        int i = 1;
        
        for(Module mod : Client.getModules()) {
            if(mod.getCategory().equals(MOVEMENT) && !mod.equals(m)) {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            
            if(mod.getCategory().equals(MOVEMENT) && mod.equals(m)) {
                return i;
            }
            
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
    public static int placeInListCombat(Module m) {
    
    
    int i = 1;
    
    for(Module mod : Client.getModules()) {
        if(mod.getCategory().equals(COMBAT) && !mod.equals(m)) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(mod.getCategory().equals(COMBAT) && mod.equals(m)) {
            return i;
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
    public static int placeInListMisc(Module m) {
    
    
    int i = 1;
    
    for(Module mod : Client.getModules()) {
        if(mod.getCategory().equals(MISC) && !mod.equals(m)) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(mod.getCategory().equals(MISC) && mod.equals(m)) {
            return i;
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
    
}
```

And the gui:

```java
package sonikhack.render;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import sonikhack.module.Category;
import sonikhack.module.Module;

public class Gui extends Module{

    public Gui() {
        super("ClickGui", Keyboard.KEY_RSHIFT, Category.RENDER);
    }
    
    public void onEnable() {
        mc.displayGuiScreen(new ClickGui());
        toggle();
    }

}
```

Comment: i mean show not shot

Comment: If you want to fix a typo you can (and should) just edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestable solution is to either make the text shorter or to try to fix it yourself. This is not a place where you can just post your code and expect someone to fix the issue. Maybe you should try learning java before coding a client. (And maybe not a hack client tbh)